# Is there a way to prevent AirPods from discharging when they are not in the case?

Tags: iphone, battery, airpods

I put AirPods in my ears and left on an overnight trip and forgot the case.  When I got to the destination, I took the AirPods out and left them unused.  The next morning the batteries on them were completely drained.

I understand that the AirPods are "on" even when not using them.  So, in the absence of the case, is there a way to turn the AirPods off so that they are not discharging.

P.S. I even turned off Bluetooth on my iPhone but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Airpods can't be turned off or put in a low-power state outside of the case.

They are in an always-on state when taken out of the case and remain that way unil returned to the case.